# How to put an upper bound over the sum of each row in a table in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I have a table called "latencies" and it encompasses 2 sets, a and b, and a variable y to iterate over this table. As well, I have some parameters for a that must be satisfied:

```
table latencies(a, b)
   b1  b2  b3
a1 1   2   3
a2 4   5   6
a3 7   9   8;

parameter pam1(a) /"a1" 12, "a2" 13, "a3" 14/; 
positive variable y(a,b);
```

I am trying to make the sum of each row from the latencies table at most each respective element in the parameter pam1.

```
equations maxime(a), ...;
maxime(a)..
   sum(a, y(a,b)) =l= pam1(a);
```

So the sum of the first row in latencies should be less than or equal to 12, the sum of the 2nd row should be less than or equal to 13, etc. However, I am getting these errors: "Set is under control already" and "Uncontrolled set entered as constant" on the same equation above. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected solution (which works):

```
  equations maxime(a), ...;
  maxime(a)..
     sum(b, y(a,b)) =l= pam1(a);
```

I was incorrectly setting the row index (a) as my controlling index before. I needed to set that index as b, the column index. That is how you would iterate over the sum of each row and put an upper bound on it.